# Errors when exporting to xlsx

Tags: r

When I try to export a dataframe, R gives me the following error:

> Error in gsub("&", "&", v, fixed = TRUE) :    input string 81 is
>   invalid UTF-8

I tried this:

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(Nits_hotel, "Nits_hotel.xlsx")
```

And also this:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Nits_hotel")
writeData(wb, 1, Nits_hotel)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Nits_hotel.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

But in both I get the same error.

Comment: Please, could you provide example of your data?

Comment: Try using `write.xlsx(Nits_hotel, "Nits_hotel.xlsx", encoding="latin1")`

Comment: With encoding="latin1" I get the same error...

Answer (score -1):

It is not the same but this works:

```
write.csv2(Nits_hotel, "Nits_hotel.csv")
```